# Algorithm for combination of single elements in separate sub-arrays

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList in Java, with each element representing an ArrayList of Strings (sub-list). I'm trying to take all possible combinations of exactly one element from each sub-list.

In the example below, we have n=3 and m=3, so 3 X 3X 3 = 27 possible combinations. But in practice, each sub-list could be of different size (i.e., some with 3 strings, some with 2, and some with 10 strings). As mentioned, the total number of sub-lists can vary as well.

For example, if `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> strArray` is:

```
[["foo", "far", "fuzz"],
 ["boo", "bar", "buzz"],
 ["hoo", "har", "huzz"]]
```

Then we should return:

```
1. ["foo", "boo", "hoo"]
2. ["foo", "boo", "har"]
. . . 
27. ["fuzz", "buzz", "huzz"]
```

The code I have so far is below, but it's way off the mark. Any ideas how I can fix the code? Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

```
class Combo2 {

List<ArrayList<String>> strArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

public Combo2() {
    strArray.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Foo","Far","Fuzz")));
    strArray.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Boo","Bar","Buzz")));
    strArray.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Hoo","Har","Huzz")));

};


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Combo2 c2 = new Combo2();
        c2.start(c2);
    }

    public void start(Combo2 c2) {
        List<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        c2.makeCombos(strArray, result);
        int i = 0;
        for (ArrayList<String> s : result) {
            i += 1;
            System.out.println(i + ": " + s);
        }
    }

    public void makeCombos(List<ArrayList<String>> arry, List<ArrayList<String>> result) {
        // Recursion end case
        if (arry.size()==1) {
            for (String s : arry.get(0)) {
                result.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s)));
            }
        }
        // Recursion normal case
        for (String s : arry.get(0)) {
            makeCombos(arry.subList(1,arry.size()), result);
            result.add(0, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s)));
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: This implementation seems harder than needed. Why are you using recursion? Is that required?

Comment: I don't see a reason to do recursion over here, the math is pretty straightforward `NC1 * NC2 * NC3` by combinations. In this case `N = 3`. You'd have to iterate for `N * M * K`  times

Comment: I assume this is homework, what are the requirements/restrictions?

Comment: The requirement is that it needs to be able to handle any number of sub-lists. That's why I tried to use recursion. I showed 3 sub-lists in the example, but it could be 4,5 or 10 sub-lists, etc. It's homework for an online class I'm auditing (no grades, or even certificate!).

Comment: I was wondering if the "early termination" I was experiencing might be due to asynchronicity, but I just explicitly made `makeCombos()` synchronous, and still got the same result. It seems like an easy problem on the surface, but it's pretty tricky to implement.

Comment: One big problem causing the "early termination" is the `return` statement inside the `for` loops. I moved those outside the `for` loops, and now I get 27 results as expected (but not yet the right results) . . .

Comment: I'm pretty convinced I will need to add another recursive function, as there are two levels of recursion involved. One level of recursion for the main list, given that it can hold any (n) number of sub-lists, and another level of recursion for each sub-list, as each sub-list can hold any (m) number of items.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you need a dummy variable, and I think you can simplify your code a little.

```
static void makeCombos(List<List<String>> combos, List<List<String>> arr, String[] curr, int i)
{
    if(i == arr.size())
    {
        combos.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(curr)));
        return;
    }

    for(int j=0; j<arr.get(i).size(); j++)
    {
        curr[i] = arr.get(i).get(j);
        makeCombos(combos, arr, curr, i+1);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
List<List<String>> arr = Arrays.asList(
  Arrays.asList("Foo","Far","Fuzz"),
  Arrays.asList("Boo","Bar","Buzz"),
  Arrays.asList("Hoo","Har","Huzz"));

List<List<String>> combos = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

makeCombos(combos, arr, new String[arr.size()], 0);

for(List<String> combo : combos)
    System.out.println(combo);
```

Output:

```
[Foo, Boo, Hoo]
[Foo, Boo, Har]
[Foo, Boo, Huzz]
[Foo, Bar, Hoo]
[Foo, Bar, Har]
[Foo, Bar, Huzz]
[Foo, Buzz, Hoo]
[Foo, Buzz, Har]
[Foo, Buzz, Huzz]
[Far, Boo, Hoo]
[Far, Boo, Har]
[Far, Boo, Huzz]
[Far, Bar, Hoo]
[Far, Bar, Har]
[Far, Bar, Huzz]
[Far, Buzz, Hoo]
[Far, Buzz, Har]
[Far, Buzz, Huzz]
[Fuzz, Boo, Hoo]
[Fuzz, Boo, Har]
[Fuzz, Boo, Huzz]
[Fuzz, Bar, Hoo]
[Fuzz, Bar, Har]
[Fuzz, Bar, Huzz]
[Fuzz, Buzz, Hoo]
[Fuzz, Buzz, Har]
[Fuzz, Buzz, Huzz]
```

Comment: Very slick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out! . . . (Needed to add an extra dummy variable into the recursive function) . . .

```
    public void makeCombos(List<ArrayList<String>> arry, ArrayList<String> dummy, List<ArrayList<String>> result) {
        ArrayList<String> newDummy;
        int idx;

        if (arry.size()==1) {
            for (String s : arry.get(0)) {
                newDummy = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i=0; i<dummy.size(); i++) newDummy.add(dummy.get(i)); // Copy dummy to newDummy
                idx = (newDummy.size()==0) ? 0 : newDummy.size(); // Find where to put new entry
                newDummy.add(idx, s);
                result.add(newDummy);
            }
            return;
        }
        for (String s : arry.get(0)) {
            newDummy = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i=0; i<dummy.size(); i++) newDummy.add(dummy.get(i)); // Copy dummy to newDummy
            idx = (newDummy.size()==0) ? 0 : newDummy.size(); // Find where to put new entry
            newDummy.add(idx, s);
            makeCombos(arry.subList(1,arry.size()), newDummy, result);
        }
        if (dummy.size()==arry.size()) dummy = new ArrayList<String>();
        return;
    }
```